# Visual Studio 2012 unresponsive in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, vmware-workstation, visual-studio-2012

After installation of **Visual Studio 2012** in Windows 8 VM via VMware Workstation 8,  I am getting this message while launching, VS 2012 have become unresponsive although I am able work it after some time. What might be the cause?

[image]

Comment: Not sure if it will help this particular issue, however it appears you are using a release candidate edition. It might be worthwhile upgrading to the final release, available at http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to increase the  Virtual RAM for VMWARE as win 8 is strong UI based OS it takes memory resource.Increase in the Virtual RAM from VMWARE configuration can help you..

Answer (score 2):

This is a VS addin/extension called PerfWatson (as the dialog shows). Apparently MS have been using the data it sends back extensively in order to improve the performance in VS. In the non-Express versions of VS you can uninstall it if you want by going to the "Extensions and Updates" item in the Tools menu - but I'm not sure if you have that ability in the Express version. You could, of course just ignore it.

It used to come up pretty much every time I ran VS in my VM but once VS was loaded it ran fine. I did, however, uninstall it in the end.

As for the cause... well, it thinks that VS should have loaded quicker! Perhaps giving the VM more RAM may help - but it might not.